# Store data on user who logged in with facebook and then access when user logs in again?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

How do I store data on users facebookID so that I can access it when user logs in again?

Comment: Hey there! There are a few details you could provide which would really help us tailor an answer to your needs. For starters, what is your environment/setup? Are you using FirebaseSimpleLogin via the web client? Are you doing custom tokens via Passport or iOS through a node.js server? What have you tried so far? Can you provide some relevant code for us demonstrating what you have now, along with any relevant parts of your data schema?

Answer (score 1):

With the facebook graph api.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/

Your user should allow your access to his/her data.

Comment: The facebook login name is between his other data. You can identify him (she) based on his facebook login.

Comment: And probably you will need to contact Facebook on both of the client side (browser) and on the server!